# What is the correct svmlight input format in Mallet?

Tags: classification, mallet, svmlight

I am using `Mallet` with the `SVMLight` input format to do `classification` using`NaiveBayes` classifier. But I get a `NumberFormatException`. I'm wondering how I can use strings features when using SVMLight. As I read in the guideline [1](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/import.php), the features can also be strings.

Can anyone help me what is wrong with my code or input?

Here is my code:

```
public void trainMalletNaiveBayes() throws Exception {

        ArrayList<Pipe> pipes = new ArrayList<Pipe>();
        pipes.add(new SvmLight2FeatureVectorAndLabel());
        pipes.add(new PrintInputAndTarget());

        SerialPipes pipe = new SerialPipes(pipes);

        //prepare training instances
        InstanceList trainingInstanceList = new InstanceList(pipe);

        trainingInstanceList.addThruPipe(new CsvIterator(new FileReader("/tmp/featureFiles_svm.csv"), "^(\\S*)[\\s,]*(.*)$", 2, 1, -1));

        //prepare test instances
        InstanceList testingInstanceList = new InstanceList(pipe);
        testingInstanceList.addThruPipe(new CsvIterator(new FileReader("/tmp/test_set.csv"), "^(\\S*)[\\s,]*(.*)$", 2, 1, -1));

        ClassifierTrainer trainer = new NaiveBayesTrainer();
        Classifier classifier = trainer.train(trainingInstanceList);
```

And here is the first three lines of my input file:

```
No f1:NP f2:NN f3:1 f4:1 f5:0 f6:0 f7:0 f8:0.0 f9:1 f10:true f11:false f12:false f13:false f14:false f15:ROOT f16:NN f17:NOTHING
No f1:NP f2:NN f3:8 f4:4 f5:0 f6:0 f7:1 f8:4.127134385045092 f9:8 f10:true f11:false f12:false f13:false f14:false f15:ROOT f16:DT f17:NOTHING
Yes f1:NP f2:NN f3:4 f4:3 f5:0 f6:0 f7:0 f8:0.0 f9:4 f10:true f11:false f12:false f13:false f14:false f15:NP f16:DT f17:NN
```

The first column is the label of the instance and there rest of the data includes the features and their values. For example, `NN` shows the `POS` of the head word of a phrase.

In the meantime, I get the exception for the `NN` (`NumberFormatException: For input string: "NN"`) . I'm wondering why it doesn't have any problem with the `NP` which comes before that, but stops at the `NN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All features need to have numeric values. For booleans you can use true=1 and false=0. You would also have to modify f1:NP to f1_NP=1.

The reason it's not dying on the NP is that the `SvmLight2FeatureVectorAndLabel` class is expecting to parse an entire line (label and data), but the code is reading the file with a `CsvIterator` that is splitting off the first element as a label.

The `classify.tui.SvmLight2Vectors` class uses this code for an iterator:

```
new SelectiveFileLineIterator (fileReader, "^\\s*#.+")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And should I add all other features with a zero value to the line. For example, when I have an NP value for a feature, it means that it is not VP, S, FRAG, etc. Should I also add f2_VP:0, f3_S:0, etc.?I mean, should I convert my categorial features to numerical features? Then, I will have a really sparse feature vector. Right?

Comment: Convert categories to features, leave out anything that's got a zero value and it will be handled efficiently.

Comment: Thanks. It works with no error now :)
Just another question, with the above format and the written code, I get name: csvline:1
target: f1_NP:1
 input: f2(0)=0.0
 f3(1)=0.0
 f4(2)=2.65
...
It seems that it is not reading my target correctly and taking a feature as the target. Is my code or input format somewhere wrong or the PrintInputAndTarget() does not work with SVMLight, and is just for the other format?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had't understood your answer correctly. I solved my problem with changing CSVIterator to SelectiveFileLineIterator and now it works perfectly :)